# error MSB3541 when deploying a Windows UWP cross platform application

Tags: visual-studio, svn, xamarin, uwp, visual-studio-2017

Recently I created a sample Xamarin cross platform application using Visual Studio 2017.  The Android project under this solution runs and it is debugged without any error, but the Windows UWP project solution, previously needs to be build and deployed in order to debug it. There is an MSB3541 error when trying to deploy UWP project.

This is the detailed error:

*Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4686,5): error MSB3541: Files has invalid value "obj\x86\Debug\DebtAppXamarin.UWP.c_.users.dafpc.documents.visual_studio_2017.Projects.DebtAppXamarin.DebtAppXamarin.DebtAppXamarin.Views.ItemDetailPage.xaml.g.cs". The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.*

The specified file **...ItemDetailPage.xaml.g.cs** actually does not exist in the directory **...DebtAppXamarin.UWP\obj\x86\Debug\**.

I have tried to clean and rebuild solution but the same problem is again.
Also I have created the same new project but the same error is present.

Is there any problem when naming project files in **obj** directory , or the error might be somewhere else?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue(Master Detail template crossplatform ) with VS 2017, could you please try to open and compile your project with VS 2015, in order to isolate the possible IDE issue? And could you provide `Xamarin.Forms` version?

Comment: I used Xamarin forms (master detail template) with VS 2017. I opened the project with VS 2015, but I have the same error. I am using Xamarin version 4.2.2.11 . @NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: Have you tried to creat new project (Master Detail template crossplatform) with VS2015? Kindly let me know how it goes.

Comment: I just created a new project ,blank template ,because there is no Master detail template with VS 2015. And it was deployed and compiled without any errors when using the UWP project under the same solution. @NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: Even when creating a blank cross platform app on VS 2017 I have the same error MSB3541.

Comment: I think you could try to reinstall the [Xamarin.Forms](https://www.xamarin.com/download-it?_bt=101035044668&_bk=xamarin&_bm=e&gclid=CJy34oGg2NICFQp7vQodHBAKeQ#download) component for VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution for my current project even by reinstalling Xamarin Forms or updating VS 2017. What I did is that I created a new cross platform project using Xamarin Forms , but this time I choose a different code sharing strategy like **Portable Class Library** (not a shared project), after setting up project template details the application was running smoothly, without any build errors or warnings.